# UE4 C++ I can't get Json Nested Values to TArray

Tags: c++, arrays, json, unreal-engine4

I'm doing a GET Request to an online API but I can't get nested Json values to set to an array in C++ (Unreal Engine 4).
I got all values except nested array **LE** (key)

**Here is JSON**

```
    {
    "Id": 8,
    "Nome": "Name",
    "DataInicial": "2018-10-01T00:00:00",
    "DataFinal": "2018-12-31T00:00:00",
    "VL": 270174.982,
    "CN": 461,
    "Met": 354940,
    "PM": 76.118493829943088972784132529,
    "LE": [
        {
            "Id": 25,
            "Nome": "Suco",
            "Cor": "#510077",
            "ValorNegociacaoGanha": 57772.452,
            "CountNegociacaoGanha": 107,
            "Meta": 66700,
            "PercentualMeta": 86.61537031484257871064467766
        },
        {
            "Id": 23,
            "Nome": "Espumante",
            "Cor": "#edd865",
            "ValorNegociacaoGanha": 52494.03,
            "CountNegociacaoGanha": 93,
            "Meta": 66700,
            "PercentualMeta": 78.701694152923538230884557721
        }
    ]
}
```

**Here is important code**

```
void AHttpActor::OnResponseReceived(FHttpRequestPtr Request, FHttpResponsePtr Response, bool bWasSuccessful) {

//Create a pointer to hold the json serialized data
TSharedPtr<FJsonObject> JsonObject;

//Create a reader pointer to read the json data
TSharedRef<TJsonReader<>> Reader = TJsonReaderFactory<>::Create(Response->GetContentAsString());

//Deserialize the json data given Reader and the actual object to deserialize
if (FJsonSerializer::Deserialize(Reader, JsonObject)) {

    //Get the value of the json object by field name
    int32 id = JsonObject->GetIntegerField("Id");
    FString nome = JsonObject->GetStringField("Nome");
    FString DataInicial = JsonObject->GetStringField("DataInicial");
    FString DataFinal = JsonObject->GetStringField("DataFinal");
    double VN = JsonObject->GetNumberField("VN");
    int32 CN = JsonObject->GetIntegerField("CN");
    int32 Met = JsonObject->GetIntegerField("Met");
    double PM = JsonObject->GetNumberField("PM");

    //Add data to array
    Arr1.Emplace(FString::FromInt(id));
    Arr1.Emplace(nome);
    Arr1.Emplace(DataInicial);
    Arr1.Emplace(DataFinal);
    Arr1.Emplace(FString::SanitizeFloat(VN));
    Arr1.Emplace(FString::FromInt(CN));
    Arr1.Emplace(FString::FromInt(Met));
    Arr1.Emplace(FString::SanitizeFloat(PM));

    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("===== GET LE ====="));
    //FString teste = JsonObject->GetField("LE");
    //UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT(teste));
    //ArrSuco = JsonObject->GetArrayField("LE");
    //TArray<TSharedPtr<FJsonValue>> objArray = JsonObject->GetArrayField("LE");
    //ArrTeste = JsonObject->GetArrayField("LE");
    //GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(1, 2.0f, FColor::Green, "printing LE...");
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("===== printing LE... ====="));
    auto arr = JsonObject->GetArrayField("LE");
    for (int32 index = 0; index < arr.Num(); index++)
    {
        //GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(1, 2.0f, FColor::Green, "name:" + FString(objArray[index]->AsString()));
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("TESTE"));

        //ArrSuco
        if (index == 0) {
            //ArrSuco.Emplace(FString::FromInt();
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Index = 0"));
            //FString teste = arr[0].Value;
            //auto arr2 = arr[0].Get()->TryGetArray;

            //UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT(arr[0].Get()->AsString()));
            //GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(1, 2.0f, FColor::Green, FString(sucoId));
            //UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT(FString(arr[index]["Id"])));
            //ArrSuco.Append(FString(arr[index]["Id"]), arr[index].Num());
            //ArrSuco.Emplace(FString::FromInt(id));
            //ArrSuco.Emplace(nome);
        }
        //ArrEspumante
        else if (index == 1) {
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Index = 1"));
        }
        //ArrCerveja
        else if (index == 2) {
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Index = 2"));
        }
        //ArrVinho
        else if (index == 3) {
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Index = 3"));
        }

        //UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT(objArray[index]->AsString()));
        //UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT(FString(ArrSuco[index])));
    }

        //Count Array
        //int32 CountArr = ArrSuco.Num();
}
```

}

I can print all (LE) indexes tests `if (index == 0)`, but I can't put it to an array.
I really don't know how to get it, I'm stuck here all the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try something like:

```
TArray<TSharedPtr<FJsonValue>> arr = JsonObject->GetArrayField("LE");
for (int32 index = 0; index < arr.Num(); index++)
{
    TSharedPtr<FJsonObject> obj = arr[index]->AsObject();
    /* get the object's fields:

    obj->GetStringField("Nome");

    */
}
```

Comment: Thank you this reply. Your reply would be greatly improved (for the requester and later for other readers) if you add some explanation as to how your code addresses the problem.